# Check if two sorted strings are equal in O(log n) time

Tags: python, string, algorithm, time-complexity

I need to write a Python function which takes two sorted strings (the characters in each string are in increasing alphabetical order) containing only lowercase letters, and checks whether or not the strings are equal.
The function's time complexity needs to be `O(log n)`, where `n` is the length of each string.

I can't figure out how to check it without comparing each character in the first string with the parallel character of the second string.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206545/discussion-on-question-by-dani-check-if-two-sorted-strings-are-equal-in-olog-n).

Answer (score 6):

This is, in fact, possible in O(log n) time in the worst case, since the strings are formed from an alphabet of constant size.

You can do 26 binary searches on each string to find the left-most occurrence of each letter. If the strings are equal, then all 26 binary searches will give the same results; either that the letter exists in neither string, or that its left-most occurrence is the same in both strings.

Conversely, if all of the binary searches give the same result, then the strings must be equal, because (1) the alphabet is fixed, (2) the indices of the left-most occurrences determine the frequency of each letter in the string, and (3) the strings are sorted, so the letter frequencies uniquely determine the string.

I'm assuming here that the strings have the same length. If they might not, then check that first and return `False` if the lengths are different. Getting the length of a string takes O(1) time.

---

As @wim notes in the comments, this solution cannot be generalised to lists of numbers; it specifically only works with strings. When you have an algorithmic problem involving strings, the alphabet size is usually a constant, and this fact can often be exploited to achieve a better time complexity than would otherwise be possible.

Comment: Using exponential search for "the other end" of known values works regardless of alphabet size.

Comment: @greybeard Yes, but if the alphabet size isn't constant then each distinct element might occur only once, and you'd end up doing *n* binary searches for the right-most occurrences of *n* distinct elements.

Comment: This approach will be slower than simple iteration for strings of size less than about 450 according to this graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7tmzw8yspg

Comment: In fact, I suspect it might be worse than that, since as the strings get longer, there will be more repetitions of each letter, meaning that once a binary search has found a particular letter, you then have to iterate through each string searching a greater distance for the leftmost occurrence.

Comment: To me, this is a perfect example of why we should only use big-o notation as a guideline. It is not entirely uncommon for a fast O(n) to beat a slow O(logn), or even for a fast O(n^2) to beat a slow O(n).

Comment: @mypetlion Thanks for doing the analysis. Binary search does not iterate through the string, since that would degrade to O(n) performance; the left-most occurrence can be found by just continuing the binary search. A slightly more optimised version of my algorithm would compare the characters at index 0, then if they're equal search for the first occurrence of a character greater than it, and so on; that would do at most 25 binary searches per string, or fewer if the strings don't use every letter. You can also just fall back to a linear comparison for n < 450 if you like.

Comment: The two approaches can also be combined, so that you fall back to a linear comparison when the index of the current character is at most a fixed number less than the string length. One should only write something so simple as "do 26 binary searches on each string" as a proof of concept!

Comment: This algorithm captures the essential insight.  A more practical way would be to recursively divide the strings into halves, but short circuit when the substrings begin and end with the same character.

Comment: I tried the simplest version `all(bisect(s, c) == bisect(t, c) for c in string.ascii_lowercase)`, that caught up with `s == t` at strings with a few hundred thousand characters.

Comment: Oh and your version has a bug. If you look for "left-most occurrence", then you won't notice differences in the number of 'z' letters.

Comment: @HeapOverflow Amazing! Not the first time I've seen it happen in Python. I suspect it's because `bisect` is implemented in pure Python, while `==` on strings is done in C of course. Regarding the `'z'` bug, I'm assuming the two strings are the same length; I thought that was implied by the question (*"n is the length of each string"*) but I suppose it could be interpreted differently.

Comment: Oh, right, I overlooked that. Still... with `bisect` it checks different lengths as well, plus it's shorter than `bisect_left` :-P

Comment: Yeah, string operations can be unbelievably fast. Like `'b' in s` with `s = 'a' * 10**7`. That checks about 4.3 **b**illion characters per second. On my 3.09 GHz CPU.

Comment: Actually `s == t` is even faster. Compares over **8** billion letter **pairs** per second on my 3.09 GHz CPU. As tested with [this](https://repl.it/repls/CuteImpressivePreprocessor). Although I'm *less* surprised about this than I was about the single character search. With comparing strings, it's more obvious that it can check multiple bytes at the same time.

Comment: @mypetlion you should not "binary" search for any given value, but for the boundary to lower/higher ones. Either starting from either end, or (even "recursively") from the middle. And yes, the boundary for being beneficial is bound to be high today and higher tomorrow.

Comment: `with [k distinct values] you'd` **inevitably** `end up doing [Ω(k) searches]` (operations) in the "equals" case.

Comment: @kaya3 How can I easily find the last occurrence of each letter using a binary search?

Comment: @Dani Binary search works by maintaining the left and right boundaries of the subarray that the search target is in. If the search target is "the first occurrence of `x`" then you should move the left boundary if the middle character is `< x` and move the right boundary if the middle character is `>= x`. Repeat until the subarray only contains one letter, and check if it's `x`. There is almost no difference to a regular binary search. There's a Python example in the `bisect` package source code; the function `bisect_right` does it. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/bisect.py#L15

Comment: Interesting solution but kind of insane/useless in practice.  If you actually have long enough strings where this complicated method is faster, it would be better to be using some kind of sparse storage in the first place like a [run length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) for example. +1 anyway, for academic interest.